# C# SQL Query for public DataTable

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, windows, multithreading

I have searched through the archive questions but can't find a suitable solution. I am sorry if one actually exists.

I am using Visual Studio 2013, .NET Runtime 4.5, MS-SQL 2008.

My code is simple:

```
public static class Global
{
    public static DataTable CityTable;
}
```

To fill my data table I call:

```
SqlCommand SC1 = new SqlComman("SELECT DISTINCT City FROM Final WHERE City !='' AND City IS NOT null AND Published LIKE '%/%/" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy") + "'", conn);

SqlDataAdapter SDA1 = new SqlDataAdapter(SC1);

SDA1.Fill(Golbal.CityTable);
```

Every time the call is made I get an error on the fill command. Error message as below:

> System.ArgumentNullException : {"Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter
>   name: dataTable"}

Can anyone help me to stop this exception?

Comment: What is your command returns in your db manager? What is your `Published` column type?

Comment: Published is a set of dates, but thats not my return column, it's the distinct City Column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try assigning an empty table before using the table variable in `SqlDataAdapter`. Something as like,

```
 SqlCommand SC1 = new SqlCommand("select distinct City from Final " +
                                 "where City!='' and city is not null and " +
                                 "Published like'%/%/" + 
                                  DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy") + "'", conn);
 SqlDataAdapter SDA1 = new SqlDataAdapter(SC1);
 Global.CityTable = new DataTable();
 SDA1.Fill(Global.CityTable);
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: Perfect !. Worked like a charm :) but i don;t have 15 reputations to give a vote UP :(  StackoverFlow really needs to work on it's Vote up feature. But just for other readers .... This is the correct Answer for my problem. Thank You Vanet :)

Comment: May I know why this answer got down-voted? If you are down-voting please put the reason as a comment...